# While using the Task[] Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I am using Tasks to do some processes. The tasks will be in a loop, I am not sure sure how many tasks/iterations will be there. It will vary time to time. How to use the Tasks? Below is my code.

```
void func1(string loc) 
{
    var CurrentDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(loc);
    Task[] tasks; // null
    int index = 0;

    foreach (DirectoryInfo D1 in CurrentDirectoryInfo.GetDirectories)
    {
        tasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>func1(d1.FullName));
        index++;
    }
```

If I use null for the `Task[] tasks`, I am getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

If I leave it unassigned, I am getting `Use of unassigned variable` error.

Comment: This is very very bad code. You should re-visit your knowledge of `StartNew` and also decide whether you need an individual task created per directory/subdirectory. Chances are... you don't (how many cores does your PC have?).

Comment: How would you go about solving the problem if `tasks` were any other data type, and you were trying to access an instance method/property?

Comment: Also the root of this question has nothing to do with tasks, so it should probably be retitled and retagged.

Comment: What might be the best solution if I want to have per sub-directory, Each task takes only less than five seconds to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list of tasks, if you do not know how many task object you need at compile time.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
```

Add newly created takss in list.

```
foreach(DirectoryInfo D1 in CurrentDirectoryInfo.GetDirectories)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>func1(d1.FullName)));
}
```

The code for creating task object for directory object does not make sense. You should consider alternative approach, you might achieve this using single task in more efficient way.

Comment: I need to wait for the tasks to finish. How Can I use the WaitAll in this case?

Comment: Yes WaitAll could be used.

Comment: How can this be done in a single thread in more effective way? I want to compute something on each task which will consume some time.

Comment: It depends on what you do in thread if processing in task is small and the task overhead is big then using single or less threads could be better approach. You can compare both after making them.

Comment: Great. So I will use the thread for the top level folders only then. Thanks :)